# Filter icon not visible in Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, blob-storage

I am on Windows 10 and using the latest version of Azure Storage Explorer(1.27.1) but I don't see the filter panel/button on the right hand side that everyone keeps mentioning. Have gone through settings to see if it has been hidden but cannot find anything.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP7U6.png]

Comment: Please provide more information, LOTS more information. Your screenshot is from another question here. Which one?

Comment: Hi, what other info would be useful? It is on Windows, latest version of storage explorer, tried connecting using SAS tokens as well as login. Screenshot is from an unrelated question (asking about filtering using tags) just to show that I don't see this filter icon in top right.

Comment: All of that. Do not add comments to your own question, but carefully lay out everything you have researched and tried and the outcome, in the question itself. There's an edit button there for a reason: use it freely to make your question better and better. Remember that we only know what you tell us, so don't assume we'll get context or details if you haven't shared them.